# Android. Xml. RelativeLayout и HorizontalScrollView

Tags: android, xml

1. Хочу сделать так, чтобы справа от статических данных был HorizontalScrollView, однако при установке атрибута: "android:layout_toRightOf" HorizontalScrollView исчезает(отсутсвует). Не подскажете в чем пролема?

2 Конечно я могу установить атрибут "android:paddingLeft" в HorizontalScrollView.
Но хотелось бы знать, почему не работает первый вариант.

Код(все внутренности я удалил, для читабельности):

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linear_layout_players"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    </LinearLayout>

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/linear_layout_players" >

    </HorizontalScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"

Comment: match_parent значит занимать **ВСЕ** доступное пространство родительского контейнера, поскольку первый контейнер занимает **ВСЕ** пространство, второму на экране не остается места

Comment: Вот, что значит свежий взгляд. Спасибо, все очевидно, но сам увидеть не смог)